# Using Sockets.io in Node to share terminal output from child process

Tags: sockets, node.js

I'm very new to Node.JS and asynchronous programming and have a challenging question. I want to fork a process from Node and then shoot that output back to the browser with Websockets, specifically the Sockets.io library. What is the best and most robust way to handle this?

The data isn't mission critical, it's just for updating the user on status. So if they leave the page, the socket can close and the child process can continue to run. It'd also be neat if there was some way to access the socket via a specific URL in Express and come back to it later (but that may be another days work).

Answer (score 1):

Use the Redis Store support of socket.io:

```
var RedisStore = require('socket.io').RedisStore;
var io = require('socket.io').listen(app);

io.set('store', new RedisStore());
```

The socket.io library use redis server to storage the data and the events.